# Scala Pattern matching: Are parametrized extractor objects possible?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Is it possible to create an Extractor object that can be used such as:

```
val x = 42

x match {
  case GreaterThan(80) => println("5")
  case GreaterThan(70) => println("4")
  case GreaterThan(60) => println("3")
  case GreaterThan(40) => println("2")
  case _ => println("1")
}
```

Now I do know that it is possible with if constructs, but I feel that it clutters my code (and seems redundant to do: `case MyMatcher(x) if MyCreteria(x) => _`), and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extractor objects that are used in `case` statements need to have an `unapply` method. Unfortunately and as **objects themselves are singletons, so no way (afaik) exists to create such parametrized objects.**

In the code below I circumvented this be creating specific singleton `object`s for each limit.

@Ákos Vandra: Maybe the following code is helpful (as it comes closest to your requirements):

```
def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
  val n = 42

  n match {
    case GreaterThan50(x) => println("5")
    case GreaterThan40(x) => println("4")
    case GreaterThan30(x) => println("3")
    case GreaterThan20(x) => println("2")
    case _ => println("somewhat")
  }
}

class GreaterThanLimit(val limit: Int) {
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[Int] = if (x > limit) Some(x) else None
}

object GreaterThan10 extends GreaterThanLimit(10)
object GreaterThan20 extends GreaterThanLimit(20)
object GreaterThan30 extends GreaterThanLimit(30)
object GreaterThan40 extends GreaterThanLimit(40)
object GreaterThan50 extends GreaterThanLimit(50)
```

## Edit 2015-09-17

With the idea from Ákos Vandra's comment, one can use `Boolean` instead of `Option[_]` and write

```
def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
  val n = 42

  n match {
    case GreaterThan50() => println("5")
    case GreaterThan40() => println("4")
    case GreaterThan30() => println("3")
    case GreaterThan20() => println("2")
    case _ => println("somewhat")
  }
}

class GreaterThanLimit(val limit: Int) {
  def unapply(x: Int) : Boolean = x > limit
}

object GreaterThan10 extends GreaterThanLimit(10)
object GreaterThan20 extends GreaterThanLimit(20)
object GreaterThan30 extends GreaterThanLimit(30)
object GreaterThan40 extends GreaterThanLimit(40)
object GreaterThan50 extends GreaterThanLimit(50)
```

Comment: Too bad the language does not support this.

Comment: There is no need to have the extractor return a value though. Might as well have a return value of type boolean.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a return value of type `Option[Boolean]`. In case of a match you have `Some(true)`, otherwise None.

Comment: Not Option[Boolean], simply Boolean: `def unapply(x: Int): Boolean = (x > limit)`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that abusing `unapply` in the way you want will be very tricky (if possible). Why you don't want to use dedicated `if` clause of `match`?

```
object GreaterThan {
  def apply(x:Int, boundary:Int) = x > boundary
}

x match {
  case x if GreaterThan(x, 80) => println("5")
  case x if GreaterThan(x, 70) => println("4")
  case _ => println("1")
}
```

It is not much more verbose than you original code.

Alternatively, you can invent some custom analogue of match:

```
class Matcher(val cond: Int => Boolean, command: => Unit) {
  def evaluate() = command
}

val matchers = Seq(
  new Matcher(_ > 80, {println("5")}),
  new Matcher(_ > 70, {println("4")}),
  new Matcher(_ > 60, {println("3")}),
  new Matcher(_ > 40, {println("2")}),
  new Matcher(_ => true, {println("2")})
)

val x = 42
matchers.find(_.cond(x)).foreach(_.evaluate())
```

But it's even more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you wouldn't just do something like this? It's not especially verbose and saves you a bit of trouble.

```
x match {
  case _ if x > 80 => println("5")
  case _ if x > 70 => println("4")
  case _ if x > 60 => println("3")
  case _ if x > 40 => println("2")
  case _ => println("1")
}
```